# ERROR: Failed to load PhotonLicensing.dll

Tags: cross-platform, multiplayer, socketserver

The logfile states that my Photon license has expired or the PhotonLicensing.dll can't be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Photon 3 you don't need a .license file if you are using Photon for free. Just delete any old .license files you still might find in your folders from upgrading etc.:

```
..\deploy\bin_Win32
..\deploy\bin_Win32_xp
..\deploy\bin_Win64
..\deploy\bin_Win64_xp
```

If you acquired a license, just copy the .license file into the above mentioned folders (depending on the environment you use).

However there is one edge case: When you unpack your SDK with the Windows Explorer built-in unpack tool your files might get blocked as they are marked as "internet download".

There are to ways to solve the problem:

1. you unpack with another tool like 7zip or winrar.
2. or you unblock the zip-file before you unpack with the Explorer built-in zip functionality - right click the “not trusted” zip-file choose “Property” and click unblock.

Comment: Unpacking with 7zip instead of the built-in Windows unzipper was really fixing this problem for me, thanks.